# Standalone image patch extraction op in Tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, convolution

In the [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d), the `tf.nn.conv2d`-operation is described to:

1. Flatten the filter to a 2-D matrix with shape `[filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, output_channels]`.
2. Extract image patches from the input tensor to form a virtual tensor of shape `[batch, out_height, out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]`.
3. For each patch, right-multiply the filter matrix and the image patch vector.

Is there an operation to apply *just* step 2? I cannot find anything like that in the API docs. I might be searching with the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now added to the tensorflow api: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#extract_image_patches

Comment: Thanks for this. I found out, however, that unfortunately the gradient of this operation is not defined (yet).

Answer (score 3):

I guess a trick to do that would be to:

1. Take a filter of shape `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, output_channels]` with `output_channels = filter_height * filter_width * in_channels`
2. Fix the value of this filter in a way that **when the filter is flattened to a 2-D matrix** (cf. your step 2)**, it is the identity matrix**. Check my example code below for a simple way to do that with `np.eye().reshape()`
3. Perform a normal `tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')`

You now have an output of shape `[batch, out_height, out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]`

---

Here is a simple code for an input image of size 3*3 with 1 channel (and batch size 1).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_value = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((1, 3, 3, 1))
input = tf.constant(input_value)
input = tf.cast(input, tf.float32)

filter_value = np.eye(9).reshape((3, 3, 1, 9))
filter = tf.constant(filter_value)
filter = tf.cast(filter, tf.float32)

output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this approach a try. It's a shame that we have to do 'unnecessary work', but it is probably faster than my current CPU-only custom op.